# Microsoft Report Viewer Showing hidden columns on exporting to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm using Microsoft Report Viewer in an ASP.Net application on the 4.0 framework.  I have the report showing fine inside the webpage, but I was recently requested to hide several columns.  I found out that through editing the Column Visibility by right clicking on the column in the .RLDC file would allow me to hide it, but I need to be able to show the hidden columns upon Exporting to Excel.  As far as I can tell Microsoft Report Viewer exports exactly what it has shown to Excel.

Does anyone know how to access or change the columns properties upon the export to excel click event on Microsoft Report Viewer 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add your own export functionality.

Set `ShowExportButton="False"` in the ReportViewer and add a new button in your page that hides the columns and then exports the report to excel.

Comment: Yeah the entire purpose (for me) was to use the built in functionality.  I've already scrapped it and gone with Interop and a gridview, but I left the question up in case someone knew a way.  Thanks for your answer.